# How to change method in existing class

Tags: python, django

I want to do the following:

- I want to change get_absolute_url method in User django.auth class.

How can I do that?

Comment: does django contrib auth have a `get_absolute_url` method ?

Answer (score 4):

If your using Django 1.5 or greater, then you can redefine the `get_absolute_url` instance method on your [custom `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) class.

Prior to 1.5, the only clean way to accomplish this would be to create your own [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) to stand in place of `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, with a `get_aboslute_url` instance method to construct absolute urls that don't follow the `/users/%username%/` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If the Django User class is otherwise fine for your needs, you can extend it. From the [Django.Contrib.Auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) docs:

> **Extending Django’s default User**
>
> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile fields. This class provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/somepath/user/%s/' % urlquote(self.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `get_absolute_url` you can override this method using the [`ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#absolute-url-overrides)

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda user: "/users/%s/" % user.username,
}
```

Overriding other methods would require making use of the swappable User introduced in Django 1.5.